# Using superscript in Tkinter label

Tags: python, tkinter, superscript

I am making a gui with python Tkinter. Now I need to show a polynomial function in result Label, and that's where i get stuck. To show the polynomial i have to write the power as superscript. Now I can use a Text box and a positive offset value to write superscript like,

```
root=Tk()
l=Text(root)
l.tag_configure("s", offset=5)
l.insert(INSERT,"X","","2","s")
l.grid(row=0)
root.mainloop()
```

But I can't figure out how to do it for a n-th order polynomial. I have the coefficients in a list, and i want to make the polynomial an insert it into the Label/Text widget. Is there a easy way to do it? 
Also I know I can use matplotlib's latex text rendering to show the polynomial in a matplotlib graph window, but i don't want that here.

Comment: Your title says "Label" but your code uses a Text widget. Those two widgets have vastly different capabilities. Do you really mean "Label", or will an answer using "Text" work?

Comment: Yes I was looking for a way to do it using Label, but the only thing I did close to superscript was using a Text box, that's why I posted my code. And yes now I can use a label or text , which ever may be useful.

Comment: You have to use a font that supports superscripts.  See this post for starters http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10098100/problems-with-superscript-using-python-tkinter-canvas  I didn't run the code in this link so don't know how well it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import Tkinter as tk
coeff = [-5,4,-3,2,1]

root=tk.Tk()
l=tk.Text(root)
l.tag_configure("s", offset=5)

#insert first coefficient manually
l.insert("insert", str(coeff[0]))
l.insert("insert","x","",str(len(coeff)-1),"s")

#use enumerate to track indexes
for idx, item in enumerate(coeff[1:],2):
    #put a plus if number is positive. If not minus sign will come from number itself
    if item >= 0:
        l.insert("insert","+","") #insert sign
    l.insert("insert", str(item)) #insert coefficient
    #insert variable if not last item.    
    if item != coeff[-1]:
        l.insert("insert","x","",str(len(coeff)-idx),"s") #insert variable and its power

l.grid(row=0)
root.mainloop()
```

If you want to change size of coefficients, you can use [tag_add and tag_configure](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_text.htm).